# google instant app starts wrong activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-instant-apps

I am developing google instant app with kotlin; I use android studio(latest version).
In my feature module, I have tree activities.
They are

```
mainActivity
splashActivity
aboutActivity
```

The flow would be splashActivity -> mainActivity -> aboutActivity

When the app is open, splashActivity runs for 3sec and move to mainActivity. Once user click a button, aboutActivity is loaded (intent is used)

If I run the app in installed version, the app behaves the way suppose to be.

However, if I run it in instant version, it goes directly aboutActivity. 
I debug the app, the app does not go through splashActivity and mainActivity at all.

The following is feature module's manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"package="com.example.tomjangtestgg.testapp.feature">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application>
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter android:order="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="tomjangtestgg.example.com"
                android:pathPattern="/splash"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter android:order="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="tomjangtestgg.example.com"
                android:pathPattern="/main"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".AboutActivity">
        <intent-filter android:order="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="tomjangtestgg.example.com"
                android:pathPattern="/about"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Has anybody have similar problem and solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your `manifest.xml`?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: feature manifest file is added.

Comment: How are you running the instant app version?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by instant app version. Do you mean emulated device API version? it use API 27 or API 28

Comment: How are you launching the app as an instant app?

Comment: Beside run button in android studio, there is menu, you can select either app or instant. I pick instant one, and run it.

Comment: Go to Edit Configuration / instantapp / General / Launch Options, then select the URL that matches your splash activity's.